# How to use jshintmojo with surefire plugin?

Tags: maven, jshint, maven-surefire-plugin, wro4j

I want to create a surefire report for jshint errors. Is there a tag I need to use in the configuration?

I tried the following but it did not work

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.cj.jshintmojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jshint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <options>maxparams:3,indent,camelcase,eqeqeq,forin,immed,latedef,noarg,noempty,nonew</options>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>lint</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <globals>require,$,yourFunkyJavascriptModule</globals>
        <reporter>jslint</reporter>
        <reportFile>${basedir}/target/jshint.xml</reportFile>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>     
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectories>
                        <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/target/</reportsDirectory>
                    </reportsDirectories>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also tried changing the jslint to checkstyle in the tag for the jshintmojo plugin.

Is there any other plugin that I could use to generate jshint reports?